# IIS certificates for only some subdomains?

Tags: asp.net, ssl, iis, ssl-certificate, iis-8

I'm working with an organization of several universities, where they are using a web application.  It's hosted on a IIS 8, with several sites set up on it.
Each site is a subdomain of each university, and has a certificate of their own.

Like:
booking.university.com, booking.university2.com, etc...

Now, there should also be test-environments set up on the server. 
For those, there are no certificates set up.

But this seems to create a problem. Logging in to test-booking, generates an encoded url in the browsers address bar, something like:
http://test-booking.university.com/(F(vM_BPcBjHyZSr8adkOfBhiJP6gUzS5xpRDGcSy2JsvlJXijxWbF9BEUBse0OWMCWQIRYnxegEdXQIQ9UelEZqaFcu2C5P8lv0-3GEfNnEOi9FEg0XZa0Q7a9sCqlaoxhE-5nosR6WAZCzJ-q0))/default.aspx

And thou some parts of the site works (for a while), the most don't. (and it does not look very nice!)

Now, could this have something to do with the certificates? Because, before the certificates where installed, both "booking.university.com" and "test-booking.university.com" did work properly.

And do i need to set up certificates for all subdomain/sites, even those who are not using https?

Or is it the fact that you have two sites that seems to come from the same domain that causes the problem? (only in the one without certificate. The other works as intended)

If I set up a new domain, like testsites.com, and add subdomains like:
test-university.testsite.com, test-university2.testsite.com - would this be a better solution?

Comment: You can create wildcard certificate for your domains, it will cover all your subdomains. For more info, please check this link - https://serverfault.com/questions/566426/does-each-subdomain-need-its-own-ssl-certificate

Comment: That strange URL is called cookieless session. You can change ASP.NET settings to avoid that.

Comment: Yes, but why does it come up now?
I haven't had any of those until the certificates where installed on the server.